# Google Tag Manager - Event - Track Download on .aspx

Tags: asp.net, events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an issue where I am trying to track the filedownloads on a website trough Google Tag Manager events. What I am doing is and already done on many websites is to find out if the "Click Url" contains any of the filetypes I am looking for like pdf, docx and so on. The issue here is that the Click Urls does not contain the information and are ending with .aspx. What is the best method to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please show some code, like the html for those links perhaps?

Comment: So.. people are sent to another page where the download starts automatically?

Comment: Yes they are sent to another page where the link is normal and contains .pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'd rephrase the question: what do these links (elements) have in common, that point to various downloadable files, and that is different from anything else, what is not a download link. This can be referred in GTM as a trigger.

Consider the following example:
 `<a class="button file_download" id="file_link_12" href="index.aspx?action=download&file_id=12">Download file</a>`

If any of these can be identified in your HTML source code, then you can use these as triggers, which describes your elements used to point to downloadable files, e.g.:

- Click Classes contains file_download
- Click ID contains file_link
- Click text equals Download file
- Click URL contains action=download

If you are able to alter the HTML code, than you can choose any of these methods above, that bests suits your needs.